# massupdate customer data in magento customer grid

Tags: magento, grid

i need to massupdate customer streetaddress using magento. for this i wrote bultupdate function in  customer grid controller. here is the query but it is not working. how can i change this query to update street address using customerid

```
 public function massUpdateAction()
{

    $customerIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer');
    $street_type = $this->getRequest()->getParam('street');

    if (!is_array($customerIds)) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select customer(s).'));
    } else {
        if (!empty($customerIds)) {

            try {
                foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {

                   Mage::getSingleton('customer/address')
            ->updateAttributes($customerIds, array('billing_street_full' => $street_type), $storeId);
                }
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('Total of %d record(s) have been Updated.', count($customerIds))
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        try {
            foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {

                $addresses  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId)->getAddressesCollection();
                foreach ($addresses as $address) {
                    $address->setData('billing_street_full', $street_type)->save();
                }
            }
             $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                 $this->__('Total of %d record(s) have been Updated.', count($customerIds))
             ); 

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Its working perfect. But i used 'street' instead of billing_street_full.